# Скролл на Panel тянет за собой задний фон формы, если цвет panel полупрозрачный

Tags: c#, winforms

Моя проблема наверно несколько тривиальна, но если найдется решение буду рад.
Есть форма, на которой установлен задний фон. На форме есть панель, привязанная к верхнему краю и на задний цвет брошена полупрозрачность. В панели циклом создаются кнопки (если это вообще важно)

Смысл в том, что при прогрузке формы, все работает нормально. Фон формы равномерен и на пустом месте и на панели
[image: Прогрузка]

Но стоит сместить скролл в сторону, как задний фон за панелью начинает ехать вместе с ним.
[image: После скролла]

Возможно ли избежать подобного и если да, то каким способом.

Заранее благодарю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Students_Book_2_._1
{
public partial class proect : Form
{
    int btnSx = 80;
    int btnSy = 20;
    int pbSx = 80;
    int pbSy = 100;
    int posBX = 30;
    int posPX = 30;
    public proect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Button[] _bt = new Button[50];
    private PictureBox[] _pb = new PictureBox[50];

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void proect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < _bt.Length; i++)
        {
            _bt[i] = new Button();
            _bt[i].Tag = i;
            _bt[i].BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            _bt[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
            _bt[i].Size = new Size(btnSx, btnSy);
            _bt[i].Location = new Point(posBX, 135);
            _bt[i].Text = "Добавить";

            panel1.Controls.Add(_bt[i]);
            posBX = posBX + btnSx + 20;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _pb.Length; i++)
        {
            _pb[i] = new PictureBox();
            _pb[i].BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            _pb[i].Location = new Point(posPX, 30);
            _pb[i].Size = new Size(pbSx, pbSy);

            panel1.Controls.Add(_pb[i]);
            posPX = posPX + pbSx + 20;
        }

        foreach (Button btn in _bt)
            btn.Click += (b, eArgs) =>
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello from button #{0}", ((Button)b).Tag));
    }


}
```

}